# How do I change my Gmail profile picture?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I opened a Gmail account and uploaded my profile picture. Later I decide to change the picture, but I cannot find how to do it after the Gmail UI has been updated.

How can I change my picture?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange! See [Google's support pages](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/35529) on how to change your profile picture.

Answer (score 4):

There are two places Gmail will look for your profile picture.

- Click on the gear at the top right of gmail site, and select  settings. Scroll down to "My Picture" & Select "Change Picture."
- **(OR)** Go to http://plus.google.com near the top right is a circle that should encapsulate your old profile picture. If you click on it, then click "Change photo.
- If In the tablet/mobile version of gmail, it does not allow changes of profile-picture. You can accomplish this with an internet-browser-app in desktop mode following the steps above **(OR)** using the google+ app by touching the circle that encapsulates you old profile picture a few times.*

  - Also if on the tablet/mobile version of gmail, you could use the hangouts app click settings then scroll down and there you have it!

[**Click here for Answer Directly From google**](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/35529?)

Comment: Appears to be out of date now.

Comment: Just updated it.