# Gmail profile picture visibility

Tags: gmail, profile-picture

I cannot set profile picture visibility for one of my profiles in Gmail. I have tried following [this guide](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/35529?hl=en). I have also looked at [How do I change my Gmail profile picture?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54764/69587)

**The problem I am facing is as follows:**

Only one accout of two is affected. For the accout that is functioning normally I can upload the picture and then set the visibility as shown on a screenshot below:

[image]

For affected account I can upload the picture, but visibility options are not present:

[image]

**Notes:**

1. My preferred option is "Visible to everyone". But when options are not visible, the behavior defaults to not visible to anyone at all even myself.
2. Both accounts names have the same form: `xyz.abcdef@gmail.com`
3. I don't have Google+ account and don't want to create one

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Removing picture completely, signing out and trying again (no luck)
2. Acccessing gmail from older HTML version of app (no option to upload the picture)
3. Sending feedback to Google (waiting for response)